# import data from excel and use it in part of xpath

Tags: java, excel, xpath

i want to import data from excel sheet and pass it to the part of Xpath. Is there any way through which we can do it? Please suggest me some way through which i can achieve it. I tried using the following code:

```
String size = sheet.getRow(24).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),size)]/input[@type='radio']")).getAttribute(size); 
System.out.println(s);
```

here what i want is import data from excel,i stored it in variable 'size' and this size variable i need in some part of my xpath.I tried using this but its printing null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted, `size` is recognized as string literal `"size"`. You want to *concatenate* the strings instead :

```
String size = sheet.getRow(24).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
String query = "//div[contains(text(),'" + size + "')]/input[@type='radio']";
String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath(query)).getAttribute(size); 
System.out.println(s);
```